GitHub Actions - Push to public repo from private repo fails
I have a GitHub Actions workflow in a private repo of an organization. I need to push a build artefact and some other stuff to a public GitHub Pages repo of the same organization.
So I came up with this workflow:
name: Release MacOS

on:
  # Allow manual builds of this workflow
  workflow_dispatch: {}
  # Run the workflow whenever a new tag named 'v*' is pushed
  push:
    #branches:
    #  - "!*"
    #tags:
    #  - "v*"

permissions:
  contents: write
  pages: write

jobs:
  build:

  .....

  upload:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build

    steps:
      - name: Checkout ***.github.io repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          repository: ***/***.github.io

      - name: Download build artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: ****
          path: ****

....


      - name: Configure git
        run: |
          git config --global user.name 'github-actions[bot]'
          git config --global user.email 'github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com'

      - name: Commit and push changes
        env:
          PAT: ${{ secrets.GIT_PAT_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          git commit -am "***"
          git push https://$PAT@github.com/***/***.github.io.git main

Step `commit and push changes´ fails with this message:
remote: Permission to ***/***.github.io.git denied to github-actions[bot].
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/***/***.github.io.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

I checked locally that my personal access token works.
I tried adding the permission section to my workflow:
permissions:
  contents: write
  pages: write

I also tried using this action
https://github.com/cpina/github-action-push-to-another-repository. It also failed.
What am I missing?
EDIT
I tried using an ssh key as @Jim Redmond suggested.

I generated the key locally
I added the key to my GitHub account
I added the key as a secret to the private repo

This my workflow now:
      - name: Set up SSH
        run: |
          mkdir -p ~/.ssh
          echo "${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
          chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
          ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

      - name: Configure git
        run: |
          git config --global user.name 'github-actions[bot]'
          git config --global user.email 'github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com'

      - name: Commit and push changes
        run: |
          git commit -am "***"
          git push


I get the same error.

It doesn't seem you are using the github.token in the commit / push step, but the PAT: ${{ secrets.GIT_PAT_TOKEN }}. Does it have the same permissions?

github.token only applies to the source repo (in this case the private repo). It can't apply to other repos.

Also, the permissions section in the workflow only applies to the repo where the workflow lives. If you want permissions on a different repo then you'll have to grant them there. (Or, y'know, use SSH.)

@GuiFalourd My personal access token should have the necessary permissions. I confirmed it locally, that I can push to the repo using the PAT.

@JimRedmond I tried using SSH, but it fails too. See my edit

My personal access token should have the necessary permissions. I confirmed it locally, that I can push to the repo using the PAT. I suggest using only one of the PAT or Github.token for permissions in the workflow, just to be sure the token you are using have the expected scope. Did you try using your PAT to perform all the workflows steps / operations?

@GuiFalourd Did you try using your PAT to perform all the workflows steps / operations?  That solved it. I used the PAT in the checkout action too and then everything worked! Thanks

Nice, I'll add an official answer :)

This issue may be related to the fact you are using both the github.token and a PAT in your workflow (PAT for commit / push and github.token for checkout and config).
Using only one of the PAT or github.token for permissions in the workflow,  with the expected scope, should resolve your issue.
Note that as it involves another repository (maybe a private one), the PAT usage may be mandatory here.
